# How to fix position of links in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I'm trying to create a menu where I would hover over a button and a bunch of sublinks would appear beneath. However, when I'm trying to do more than one button in one line, let's say I hover over the second button, it's links still appear beneath the first button.

Here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Vezba</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Website</h1>
    <header>
   <ul>
       <li><a class="fb" href="https://Facebook.com"></a></li>
       <li><a class="reddit" href="https://Reddit.com"></a></li>
       <li><a class="yt" href="https://YouTube.com"></a></li>
   </ul>
        </header>
    <nav>
        <div class="dd">
            <button id="btn">First</button>
            <div class="ddb">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
            <button id="btn2">Second</button>
            <div class="ddb2">
                <a href="#">Link 4</a>
                <a href="#">Link 5</a>
                <a href="#">Link 6</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <br />
    <br />
    <article>
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
        Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s,
        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
        remaining essentially unchanged.
        It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages,
        and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
    </article>


        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="Message();"/>

</body>

</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body
{
    background-color:beige;
}
header
{
    text-align:center;
}
ul
{
    display:inline-block;
}
li
{
    list-style-type:none;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
}
a:link,a:visited,a:hover,a:active
{
    background-size:cover;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    color: white;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
a.fb:link, a.fb:visited,a.fb:hover, a.fb:active {
    background-image:url(../img/fb.png);
}
a.reddit:link, a.reddit:visited,a.reddit:hover, a.reddit:active {
    background-image:url(../img/reddit.png);
}
a.yt:link, a.yt:visited,a.yt:hover, a.yt:active {
    background-image:url(../img/yt.png);
}
nav
{
    font-size:10px;
    background-color:gray;
}
.dd
{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.dd button
{
  width:100px;
}
.ddb, .ddb2 {
    display:none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color:gray;
    position:absolute;
}

.ddb a, .ddb2 a{

    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
}

/*.dd:hover .ddb {
    display:grid;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}*/
article
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius:10px;
    font-size:9px;
    margin-right:200px;
    padding:2px;
}
button
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}
h1
{
    text-align:left;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family:Andalus;
}
```

**JavaScript/JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#btn").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".ddb").show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(".ddb").hide();
        }

    });

    $("#btn2").on({
        mouseenter: function () {
            $(".ddb2").show();
        },
        mouseleave: function () {
            $(".ddb2").hide();
        }

    });

});


function Message()
{
    alert("Ordered!");
}
```

Or if its gonna make it easier, I added it to jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gwwxuvka/

Again, troublesome part is the buttons below, the missing picture menu part works fine. Best I could get out of this mess was first button links appear normally, and second button links span across both the button's area when hovered over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is no need to use jquery for this simple task. just do it like this as i did. Here is Jsfiddle link

[https://jsfiddle.net/gwwxuvka/14/](http://[1]:%20https://jsfiddle.net/gwwxuvka/14/)

Comment: Thanks, I was only using Jquery as practice, thats why I had the CSS part commented out, but placing the buttons under separate divs rather than putting them in same one did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

The common way to style this is to have the button and it's corresponding drop down menu within their own container which has `position: relative;`. Then, on the drop down just apply `position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0;` and it should be nicely in place.

This will also remove the need for any JavaScript, as you can use CSS selectors such as `.menu-button:hover .ddb2` to know when the drop down should be shown.

for example...

HTML

```
<span class="menu-button">
  <button id="btn2">Second</button>
  <div class="ddb2">
    <a href="#">Link 4</a>
    <a href="#">Link 5</a>
    <a href="#">Link 6</a>
  </div>
</span>
```

CSS

```
.menu-button {
  position: relative;
}

.ddb2 {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}

.menu-button:hover .ddb2 {
  display: block;
}
```

[and here's an updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/gwwxuvka/15/)

This also removes the need for having different class names, making all the code look a little nicer.